# Find functional changes between two revisions of a file (compile diff?)

Tags: c, merge, diff

I'm looking for a tool that checks whether two (C) source code files generate the same binary so that I can find actual functional changes between two files and ignore mere coding style changes.
It would be great if this worked even within a file for different changesets, so a file may have changed in coding style on some places, but also had one functional patch added.

Comment: Could you just compile them both?

Comment: Note however, that two binaries may be functionally identical, yet be bitwise different.

Comment: I know such program. It's called compiler :)

Comment: compile the two source code and  run the md5sum command on both binaries to see if the two binaries are the same

Comment: it's way more than one file but a large project, just ruling out each file that creates the same binary would make it a lot easier to merge an old branch.

Comment: Even "recompiling" wouldn't necessarily work.  As Oli Charlesworth pointed out, even two binaries that may be "functionally identical" could easily have different checksums.

Answer (score 1):

It's very very hard to write a program to figure out the "functional" result of another program. Such a program sounds like it would be necessary for this. I would guess that computer programs themselves are right about the most compact and machine-readable way we have to even describe functionality, so it's kind of hard to write a program that analyses a program and generates a "better" description.

Somehow abstracting out and "understanding" that coding style differences don't affect functionality also sounds very, very hard. I find it hard when manually reading other people's code somehow, because the differences in style can be pretty large, even though the end result might be the same in "my style".

I would be surprised if a solution wouldn't also require a solution to the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), which is proven impossible for the general case.

Comment: The OP's requirement is somewhat more concrete, namely *generate the same binary*

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to compile both with the same compiler options and do a binary diff.

It's not only style changes you'd have to look out for; someone may have extracted code to a function that gets inlined in an optimised build.  This may, or may not, depending on compiler options and version, give the same binary.

Comment: Note that some object file formats include a compilation time, so the comparison of the binary files needs to take that into account.  This comment applies to others of the answers above, too.

Answer (score 0):

- Mapping binary back to source to "high level functionality" - unlikely.
- Comparing two source files with respect to "high level functionality" (ignoring coding style) - possible:

  http://cscope.sourceforge.net/
- Alternative suggestion:

  Write a tool that "normalizes" your source files - by applying the *same* formatting to *both* sets of code.

  This can easily be automated.

  For example:

  1) checkout both from version control,

  2) apply "standard format",

  3) compare

Comment: I don't want to diff the binary, knowing whether they produce the same binary or not would be sufficient. How would you suggest using cscope here?

Comment: Aren't 'diff the binary' and 'knowing whether they produce the same binary' the same in principle? Since a binary diff typically results in 'same' or 'not same'.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're interested in is whether they both "generate the same binary", then the easiest solution is simply to generate both binaries, and compare.

Note, however, that there are things that would result in binaries that are bitwise different, even though they're functionally identical:

- Change in external function names
- Optimisations
- Reordering non-dependent code snippets
- etc.

Comment: Yes, but how would I automatize this for all the object files?

Comment: @user1150854: With a cunning script?

Comment: I thought maybe someone did this before ;) I'm afraid I don't know enough about makefiles, e.g. how would I tell a compiler to just create a single object file in the given project environment so that I can then replace the source file, do it again and compare, repeating for all files?

Comment: @user1150854: In principle, if you have a makefile rule along the lines of `%.o: %.c ...`, then invoking `make foo.o` ought to be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

There is a branch of computer science that deals with concurrency and parallel processes.
One of the applications is deciding whether two systems are behaviorally equivalent (in some [bisimulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisimulation) relation (weak or strong)).

Though it's computationally very difficult to decide whether two large systems are behaviorally equivalent. The usage is mainly for verification of small critical applications where we can't afford failure.